# How would I go about proving injections going both ways from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ for every $n \geq 2$?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, induction

I need to assert a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by showing that there are injections between the two sets.

I was provided the lemma: $A \leftrightarrow B, C \leftrightarrow D \implies A \times C \leftrightarrow B \times D$.

I have a very limited understanding of how to approach the proof. I think I can use some axiom of induction, but I am not sure where to start.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you know how to construct an injection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Your lemma is not sufficient to prove this (unless we have like $|\mathbb{R}|=2^{\aleph_0}$.)

Comment: Perhaps (x,y) belong to R^2. Then x = a1,a2,...,an.b1,b2,... y = c1,c2,...,cm.d1,d2,... Where ai, bi, ci, di belong to {0,...,9}. f:R^2 -> R be f(x,y) then just interleave x and y. If the lemma for R^n to R isn't sufficient, how could i prove said relationship?